# Executing a function based on an event where a function returns in c, is this possible in runtime?

Tags: c++, c, tandem, hp-nonstop

the issue I'm experiencing , is certain applications make use of a library that has been created to include logging , we cannot recompile the code for the running applications as they are legacy applications.

so I need to add functionality in the library file and relink the source code with the library files.

a function defined in the library file called DEBUG_DATA()

-> returns function name line etc.
-> this function is already used in the application ,
what I am required to do is on execution of this function DEBUG_DATA
I need to add an event and trigger an event once the function that calls debug_data returns.

is it possible to create a trigger on an event in c where the trigger isn't called ?
can this be done in runtime ? as in tweaking the stack?

EDIT: this is added to DEBUG_DATA():

```
void Dynatrace_Method_START(
   const char *ms_FunctionName, const char *ms_FileName, int ms_LineNO)
{
#ifdef DT_USE /*a global variable needs to be initiated for stack trace lets call it int Dyna_M_SERIAL*/
    DT_Current_Stack++;
    if (DT_Current_Stack<=DT_STACK) {
        // FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(ms_FileName);
        Dyna_M_SERIAL++;
        fprintf(pfile,"%d,mstart,%s,%s,%d,%s,%d\r\n",
            Dyna_UID, ms_FunctionName, FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(ms_FileName), ms_LineNO,
            sProgram_‌​name, Dyna_M_SERIAL);
        Line_Reference[Dyna_M_SERIAL]=ms_LineNO;
    }
#endif
}
```

OS is Guardian H Series TNS\E, compiler is Compaq ETK -NSE.

Comment: Modifying the stack can be detected by the operating system (or an antivirus program) as a malicious program is running, and your program may be marked as a virus or other hacking malware.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really get your question? Could you show s.th. you've tried or interface declarations?

Comment: You can hook the function.

Comment: Is this a library (.lib) or dynamic link library (.dll)?

Comment: Is DEBUG_DATA can be call several time in the function ?

Comment: Can you disassemble the code of DEBUG_DATA ? Is patching the DLL can be an acceptable solution ?

Comment: What can you change ? You can do what you want if instead of calling your `debug_data()` function, you just instantiate an object whose constructor calls your existing debug_data(), and destructor calls your new event function. (This is feasible for C++ code, not for C)

Comment: @Joachim:   there won't be an issue regarding antivirus as the applications run on main frame.

Comment: @ Michael: how do you hook a function ?

Comment: @Dialecticus: its .tlo its a library function for Non Stop KErnel Tandem , gaurdian OS

Comment: @ Nos: unfortunately its only c

Comment: I can basically change the code of the .tlo library and recompile the library , thereafter relink it

Comment: this I added to debug data :

Comment: void Dynatrace_Method_START(const char *ms_FunctionName, \
        const char *ms_FileName, \
        int ms_LineNO)
{
 

 #ifdef DT_USE
 /*a global variable needs to be initiated for stack trace
   lets call it 
   int Dyna_M_SERIAL*/
  

    DT_Current_Stack++;
    

   if (DT_Current_Stack<=DT_STACK)
   {

    
    
   // FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(ms_FileName);
    Dyna_M_SERIAL++;
    fprintf(pfile,"%d,mstart,%s,%s,%d,%s,%d\r\n"
      ,Dyna_UID,ms_FunctionName,FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(ms_FileName),ms_LineNO,sProgram_name,Dyna_M_SERIAL);

    Line_Reference[Dyna_M_SERIAL]=ms_LineNO; 
   }
 #endif
}

Comment: I need to call the following at the end of of the function that called debug data:

Comment: void Dynatrace_Method_END(const char *me_FunctionName, \
        const char *me_FileName \
        )
{

 int me_LineNO;


 
 #ifdef DT_USE

  if (Dyna_M_SERIAL>0)
  {
   me_LineNO= Line_Reference[Dyna_M_SERIAL];
   //FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(me_FileName);
   
   fprintf(pfile,"%d,mend,%s,%s,%d,%s,%d\r\n"
       ,Dyna_UID,me_FunctionName,FILE_NAME_STRIPPER(me_FileName),me_LineNO,sProgram_name,Dyna_M_SERIAL);
   Dyna_M_SERIAL--;
  }

 #endif
}

Comment: it basically sends triggers to a monitoring system , and measures time on the other end, somehow I need to trigger the above when the function that calls debug data ends

Comment: @ Jarod42: debug_data can get called multiple times, however alot of the time its only called once per function

Comment: I have a feeling the answer will require more than just C/C++. What is this OS, what is the compiler? I think this requires the knowledge of assembler for this particular mainframe.

Comment: OS is Guardian H Series TNS\E, compiler is Compaq ETK -NSE

Comment: Regarding ["hooking" a function...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743771/function-hooking-in-c).  But you need to wait for one to many calls to DEBUG_DATA(), and since you need to wait until the _calling_ function exits this technique may not be the solution, .

Comment: @Dialecticus - I agree with your statement _the answer will require more than just C/C++_.  But even if access to the disassembled code was available, how would that help since he is constrained by legacy (and unchangeable) executable code?

Comment: @ryyker, In Windows it is possible to reroute dll calls, so a proxy function could run this prolog and epilog code. I don't know how this is done, but am pretty sure it's doable. Maybe something similar is doable in this Guardian H OS, who knows...

Comment: Are you sure that `DEBUG_DATA()` is actually a function and not a preprocessor macro?  The only way I am familiar to pull the source file name, function name, and line number is to use macros such as `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, etc.  Since these return the values of the current function, they are usually wrapped in macros to which then call the actual debugging function.  For instance `#define DEBUG_DATA() debug_data_func(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)` or just do the string manipulation `#define DEBUG_DATA() "File: " __FILE__ " Function: " __FUNCTION__ " Line: " __LINE__`

Comment: hi David well its a function that does make use of macros:

Comment: #define debug_data(message) \
 clib_debug_data(message,__FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__)

Comment: applogies you are correct its a preproccessor macro

Comment: In "legacy" code, you could replace the calls to the underlying library function by using BINDER to link in your own function of the same name. This could call the original function (you could rename it using BINDER).  Similar functionality is available with eld in the TNS/E environment as several commercial products use it for application-transparent data replication and security.

Comment: @Andy: if the function names are unknown ? so for a generic sloution where it applies to all functions that contain a sub call to a known function is this still possible ?

Comment: @CK_ONE If you want to intercept calls to known function X from generic program(s) which call X without knowing/caring where they call X, then this is possible. I suspect that I may be missing out a level of indirection in my understanding of your question. Apologies for delay, been off SO for a few weeks.